# How can I ensure users enter data in the correct table columns (besides number formatting and magnitude limits)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I'm looking for some user interface design help. I have a JTable that has 4 columns. So the columns are ordered left to right: Chair Height, Chair Price, Table Height, Table Price.

I can ensure users don't enter heights in the price columns by setting limits on the input magnitude and decimal places. However, the values that would go in the chair height column are very similar to those that would go in the table height column.

The users get all 4 measurements at once. So sometimes they put all the chair measurements in the table columns and vice versa. I'm somewhat new to interface design. Has anyone dealt with this before? What is the best practice? Warning labels, color coding the columns (I tried this and am not thrilled), etc?

Comment: JSpinner or JFormattedTextField as TableCellEditor

Comment: Maybe if the users are able to change the order of the columns, they can enter their values more 'naturally' based on the order they are used to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best practice?

Creating a data entry form.

Rather than have your users fill in a JTable, you create an entry form that looks something like this.

```
Chair Height: _________________     Chair Price: _____________
Table Height: _________________     Table Price: _____________
```

You create this data entry form using JLabels and JTextFields.  You'll use the GridBagLayout to align the labels and fields.

Comment: Thanks! This basically confirmed to me that I should have an input dialog pop up when they double-click a row. That way the data is clearly separated and they're not trying to look back up at a column title.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I was just dealing with this issue yesterday (in javascript). There are a couple of ways to handle, but one is through smart exception handling. The following example (again Javascript, sorry) is event handling after a button click to popup a dialog window to get an integer (number of months). Here's how I handled it

```
try {
  var months = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter number of previous months to include", ""));
  this.value = months;
  //alert(document.getElementById('olderChanges').value);
} catch (ex) {
  alert('Invalid Number');
}
```

Hope that maybe this gives you some insight

Comment: Exception handling is definitely important here. Thanks!